# how to implement a different thread inside the service in XAMARIN

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, service

What I am trying to do is to run the activity while having a background process when a button is pressed. (Because my real problem is when I am having a very long process, my front-end is being stopped for a while)

What I tried to do is to make a service and bind to it (which I don't know if I made it right since I thought it will work independently). But still, when I am trying to access the method from the service, my foreground is still being stopped for a while.

**HOW CAN I ACHIEVE TO MAKE MY FOREGROUND STILL RUNNING WHILE WAITING FOR THE RESPONSE OF WEB SERVICE IN THE BACKGROUND
(I ALREADY MADE IT WITH PROGRESS BAR TO MAKE THE USER AWARE IT IS STILL LOADING)**

Here is my service, serviceConnection and binder code: // it is still useless, i'm just trying to test this

```
[Service]
public class MyService : Service
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(MyService).Name;
    int i;
    #region Override OnCreate()
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "MyService started", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Override OnDestroy
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();

        StopSelf();
        Log.Debug(TAG, "MyService destroyed at {0}.", DateTime.Now);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Override OnBind
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return new MyBinder(this);
    }
    #endregion

    public string GetTimestamp(string value)
    {
        // this is just a testing

        if (value == string.Empty)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
            {
                if (i == 100000)
                    Log.Debug(TAG, "100000 zxc");
                if (i == 500000)
                    Log.Debug(TAG, "500000 zxc");
            }
            return "empty";
        }
        else
            return i.ToString() + " from service";
    }
}

public class MyBinder : Binder
{
    MyService service;
    public MyBinder(MyService service)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(service.ApplicationContext, "my binder", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        this.service = service;
    }

    public string GetFormattedTimestamp(string value)
    {
        return service?.GetTimestamp(value);
    }
}

public class MyServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
    static readonly string TAG = typeof(MyServiceConnection).FullName;

    public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }
    public MyBinder Binder { get; private set; }

    public MyServiceConnection()
    {
        IsConnected = false;
        Binder = null;
    }

    public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder)
    {
        Binder = binder as MyBinder;
        IsConnected = Binder != null;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnServiceConnected zxc");
    }

    public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnServiceDisconnected zxc");
        IsConnected = false;
        Binder = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: look into using async/await and Tasks

Comment: Or learn Reactive Extension.